# How much data can AngularJS handle and manipulate?

Tags: json, angularjs

I am wondering if AngularJS can handle data (JSON) as big as 10mb without affecting the performance of a website?

In my case I am building a website for filtering different types of food and I have quite a lot of fields for each JSON object eg:

```
 foodtype
 foodTitle
 fooddescription
 foodDuration
 foodratings
 foodLevel
 foodurl
 foodArtwork
 foodingredients []
 foodMethod []
```

I do this to display the contents in a div:

```
<div ng-click='selectMeal(meal)' class="contentItem" ng-repeat='meal in recipes | filter:searchText | filter:duration | limitTo : paginationLimit()' ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{ meal.url }})'}">
                    <span id="contentItemHeader">{{ meal.title }}</span>
                    <span id="contentItemLevel">{{ meal.level }}</span>
</div>
```

Imagine that but with about 1000 records. I am relatively new to web backend but I'm getting the hang of it :)

P.S. This site is for filtering data so that means I'm gonna have sliders, checkboxes etc would AngularJS be able to handle so much data or there is a relative limit?

Comment: In terms of usability, it is better to filter the records somehow rather than show all 1000 records.  Also, 1000 records will not likely be 10mb

Comment: @pixelbits yea i have implemented pagination but was just wondering :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me, this question is being asked from a improper perspective. You should actually ask, whether your browser will be able to handle such a huge block.

I am personally working on an application that at a time manipulates more than 3K records at a time, and mind it, i iterate over these records, sort them, manipulate them.

Hence, personally i assume that there's nothing very specific to AngularJs when it comes to the size of your data being manipulated. But you should definitely consider the client browser restrictions while deciding your data size..